# PHP calculate the time remaining for a future time

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I am trying to implement a countdown timer on a mobile app based on some server feature. I have my server side implemented in PHP and I can't get my head around why it's off by 6 minutes.

```
Route::post('time', function () {


    $data = [];

    $data['timestamp'] = strtotime('next saturday 18:00:00.000');
    $data['date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next saturday 18:00:00.000'));
    $data['time'] = date('H:m:s', strtotime('next saturday 18:00:00.000'));


    $data['date_now'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));
    $data['time_now'] = date('H:m:s', strtotime('now'));


    $now = new DateTime();
    $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

    $future_date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('next saturday 18:00:00.000')));

    $future_date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

    $interval = $future_date->diff($now);

    $data['remaining_days'] = $interval->d;
    $data['remaining_hours'] = $interval->h;
    $data['remaining_minutes'] = $interval->m;
    $data['remaining_seconds'] = $interval->s;


    return $data;
});
```

The response I get is as follows

```
{
    "timestamp": 1530381600,
    "date": "2018-06-30",
    "time": "18:06:00",
    "date_now": "2018-06-24",
    "time_now": "03:06:04",
    "remaining_days": 6,
    "remaining_hours": 14,
    "remaining_minutes": 0,
    "remaining_seconds": 56
}
```

I have tried like all different ways to specify the time in `strtotime` but it keeps on giving me the time `"18:06:00"` in real I want `"18:00:00"`.

Regardless of the issue I have hear I really want to find the remaining time  until next saturday 6 PM of the server time. That's why I am doing `$future-$now`. But it's off by like 7 hours from the time I get from [this](https://datayze.com/time-until.php?date=June%2030th%2C%202018&hours=18&minutes=00&time_display_type=days&off=&include_type=all).

Can anyone shed me some light here?

Comment: It is not adding 6 minutes... `m` is for month. `i` is for minutes.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks @Gabriel. Any pointers on time difference issue?

Comment: If your server's timezone isn't `America/Los_Angeles`, most probably it's that the first `strtotime`s are working in the server's timezone and then your `Date` instances on `America/Los_Angeles`. Set the timezone at the beginning instead (`date_default_timezone_set()`).

Comment: @Fawzan Changing `Y-m-d H:m:s` to `Y-m-d H:i:s` already fixes your offset issue. I guess when you use the same selector a second time, it will simply reuse the first selected value. This can also be confirmed by using another date (i.e. `next sunday`, without changing the format).